# Copy only filtered data to a new workbook with vba

Tags: excel

I am trying to filter data in an excel worksheet, copy the filtered data only and move it to a new workbook. However, when I complete that step, I still have access to the other options. For example, I filter for Cars in column A but when I copy to the new workbook, I see Cars and the other options which I did not filter for like Buses and bikes and I can select them as well. Can you look at my code and see what i could change to copy and paste only car data in the workbook? Note, I have tried the special type cells code and it did not work. The coding is below:

```
Sub getdata()
    Dim newWB As Workbook
    Dim folderPath As String, filename As String, fullPath As String

    FolderPath = Config.Range("CurrentQuarterFolderPath").Value
    fileName = "mycars.xlsx"
    FullPath = folderPath & Application.PathSeparator & fileName
    Workbooks.Add

    Set newWB = ActiveWorkbook

    On Error Resume Next

    Tests_trans.ShowAllData
    Tests_trans.Range("$A$2:$O$2").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criterial:="=*Cars*", _
                      Operator:=xlAnd

    Worksheets("Allvehicles").Cells(1,1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select

    Tests_trans.Copy After:=newWB.Worksheets(newWB.Sheets.Count)
```

Please help me

Comment: Looks like you're copying the entire sheet and pasting it into the the new workbook with everything included. Adding a new a sheet then copy pasting the data into the new sheet would fix it I think.

Comment: Looks like you tried to lego together random bits of code. Please qualify all your objects (workbooks, sheets) then just copy paste the filtered range instead of the entire sheet.